# Pine-script : RSI Indicator color the line

Tags: pine-script

I use the basic RSI Indicator

Here the code

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, 
timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

I need to have the line in green when it's up 50% and in red when it's down 50%
I have no find solution so if you can help me : it will be cool.

Thanks by advance for your help.

Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `color` variable for the color and use ternary operator to set its value.

```
color rsi_color = rsi >= 50 ? color.green : color.red
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=rsi_color)
```

Your full code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
color rsi_color = rsi >= 50 ? color.green : color.red
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=rsi_color)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  Works perfect.

Have a good day.

Comment: No worries. I see that you are new to Stackoverflow. I would like to kindly tell you that, when your question has an answer that you are satisfied with, it would be nice of you to accept it as an answer. By doing that, we would know that the question has an asnwer, so we do not need to visit the question again, and the person who answers you can get some reputation. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?